# C++ encrypting ascii value printing return key from array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, casting, ascii

I have this function. And its goal is to take the last character first of an array, uppercase the character if it is a letter. If it is a return key (ASCII value 10 ) or blank line, print that out too. All other characters, dont print. Note my sentinel_value = 10. Its working fine except for my else statement. It's not printing the return key. The output is all on one line. Any suggestions?

```
void EncryptMessage (ofstream& outFile, char charArray[], int length)
{
    int index;
    int asciiValue;
    int asciiValue2;
    char upperCased;
    char finalChar;


    for (index = length-1; index >= 0 ; --index)
    {
        upperCased = static_cast<char>(toupper(charArray[index]));
        if (upperCased >= 'A' && upperCased <= 'Z')
        {
            asciiValue = static_cast<int>(upperCased) - 10;
            finalChar = static_cast<char>(asciiValue);  
            outFile << finalChar;
        }
        else
        {
            asciiValue2 = static_cast<int>(charArray[index]);
            if (asciiValue2 == SENTINEL_VALUE)
            {
                outFile << asciiValue2;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asciiValue2` is an `int`, so it's ASCII value is inserted in the stream (two characters, '1' and '0'), not it's character representation. Declare `asciiValue2` as `char` and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

ascii 10 is just a line feed.  EOL characters differ depending on the system you are on 
windows = CR LF
linux = LF
osX = CR

Instead of 
`outfile<<asciiValue2;`

try 
`outfile<<endl;`

endl expands to the EOL character sequence for the system you are on.